# Checking if the roots of a function are real

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials, special-functions

I'm trying to determine if the roots of a function are real. How would you do that?

(In particular I'm interested in verifying that the roots of `LegendreP[6, x]` are real.)

Comment: You can try checking that the imaginary part is zero.  We can get the list of roots using `x /. {ToRules[Reduce[LegendreP[6, x] == 0, x]]}`.  Then we map `Im` to each root using `Map[Im,%]`, which gives `{0,0,0,0,0,0}`.  This seems to suggest that the roots are real, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @JONASS A good question, although seem very easy at first sight !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This question is not trivial as it would seem and a detailed discussion could help to understand the issue, especially when we deal with roots of special functions, however to do the task as simply as possible this would be the best way :

```
f[x_] := LegendreP[6, x] 
Reduce[f[x] == 0, x, Reals] == Reduce[f[x] == 0, x]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

`Reduce[f[x] == 0, x, Reals]` selects only real roots of `f[x]` i.e. `LegendreP[6, x]`, while `Reduce[f[x] == 0, x]` finds all roots.  The equality means that we have all roots real.

This way is good enough, because one can easily verify that `LegendreP[6, x]` is a real function, but if it hadn't been the case we should have rather used another condition assuring the expression to be real,  e.g. assume we have another function `h[x]` not necessarily real and we'd like to find when  `f[x] == h[x]` under assumption that `f[x]`  and `x` are real, then we could do this :

```
Reduce[ f[x] == h[x] && Element[ f[x], Reals], x, Reals]
```

**Edit**

There are many ways to find only real roots of a polynomial

```
PolynomialQ[ f[x], x]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

however a method above based on `Reduce` is the simplest and powerful enough to verify that we have all roots real, just because it yields the results in the form `Root` objects. Another way would be `Root`, but now to write all roots one should know that we have 6 roots (it is not difficult since `Exponent[f[x], x]` yields `6`).

```
Root[ f[x], #] & /@ Range[6]
```

> ```
> { Root[-5 + 105 #1^2 - 315 #1^4 + 231 #1^6 &, 1],  
>   Root[-5 + 105 #1^2 - 315 #1^4 + 231 #1^6 &, 2], 
>   Root[-5 + 105 #1^2 - 315 #1^4 + 231 #1^6 &, 3], 
>   Root[-5 + 105 #1^2 - 315 #1^4 + 231 #1^6 &, 4], 
>   Root[-5 + 105 #1^2 - 315 #1^4 + 231 #1^6 &, 5], 
>   Root[-5 + 105 #1^2 - 315 #1^4 + 231 #1^6 &, 6]}
> ```

Selecting only real roots yields the same number of roots

```
Select[%, Re[#] == # &] // Length
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

To elaborate a bit, let's try the other methods e.g. `Roots`, `Solve` . To write all root in lists we can do the following :

```
r = List @@ Roots[f[x] == 0, x][[All, 2]];
s = Solve[f[x] == 0, x][[All, 1, 2]];
```

here we show e.g.  `s` :

[image]

As one can see the output does not seem apparently real just as in case of writing the output of `Reduce` in the form of radicals :

```
ToRadicals @ Reduce[ f[x] == 0, x]
```

One way to assure that roots are only real would be applying `FullSimplify` with an appropriate `ComplexityFunction` to radicals, but it can take too much time, e.g. try `FullSimplify @ s`.  Instead of simplifying algebrically the expression, one can check the numerical result, e.g.

```
Im @ N[s, 100]
```

> ```
> {0.*10^-101, 0.*10^-101, 0.*10^-101, 0.*10^-101, 0.*10^-101,  0.*10^-101}
> ```

we can apply `N` directly to `Reduce` as well :

```
N @ Reduce[ f[x] == 0, x]
```

> ```
> x == -0.238619 || x == 0.238619 || x == -0.661209 || 
> x ==  0.661209 || x == -0.93247 || x == 0.93247
> ```

If we assume directly only real solutions to be found with `Solve`, they will be represented by `Root` objects as in the case of  `Reduce` :

```
Solve[ f[x] == 0, x, Reals][[All, 1, 2]] == List @@ Reduce[ f[x] == 0, x, Reals][[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Now it'll be enlightening to plot the roots :

```
roots = Tuples[{ List @@ Reduce[ f[x] == 0, x][[All, 2]], {0}}];
Plot[ f[x], {x, -1, 1},
            PlotStyle -> Thick, 
            Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Darker @ Green, Point @ roots}]
```

[image]

and to show the relevant structure of real and imaginary parts of `LegendreP[6, x]` in the complex plane :

```
GraphicsGrid[{
    { Plot3D[ Re @ f[x + I y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Filling -> 0, 
              FillingStyle -> {{Opacity[0.5], Lighter @ Blue}, {Opacity[0.5], Green}}, 
              PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4 ], 
      Plot3D[ Im @ f[x + I y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, Filling -> 0, 
              FillingStyle -> {{Opacity[0.5], Lighter@Blue}, {Opacity[0.5], Green}}, 
              PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 4]}, 

    { ContourPlot[ Re @ f[x + I y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
                   Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Darker[Green, 0.7], Point @ roots}], 

      ContourPlot[ Im @ f[x + I y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
                   Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Darker[Green, 0.7], Point @ roots}]}}]
```

[image]

The option `Filling -> 0` helps us to mark the level `Re @ f[z] == 0` and `Im  @ f[z] == 0` in `Plot3D`'s and the green points on `ContourPlot`'s denote the real roots in the complex plane as in the `Plot` above of the function in the real domain.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/259174/code-for-calculating-the-number-of-real-roots-of-the-polynomial

Answer (score 5):

If you are only interested in roots of `LegendreP`, then you might be better off using a theorem (found e.g. in Szegő, *Orthogonal Polynomials*) which states:

> The zeros of the orthogonal polynomials $p_n(x)$, associated with the distribution $d\alpha(x)$ on the interval $[a, b]$, are real and distinct and are located in the interior of the interval $[a, b]$.

The part of its proof you are interested in - which is the fact that all roots are real - makes use of Sturmian sequences, so perhaps you might want to try playing around with them.

Comment: There's a slicker proof: there exists a *symmetric* matrix whose characteristic polynomial is the (monic) Legendre polynomial. Show that a symmetric matrix always has real eigenvalues, and you're done. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/12209) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

I might as well. There is a method that works only for polynomials, but this works for checking if all the roots of a polynomial are real. The method is based on work by [Miroslav Fiedler](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795%2890%2990323-5) and [Gerhard Schmeisser](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795%2893%2990268-S). Briefly, the method constructs (or tries to construct) a tridiagonal companion matrix from your polynomial (i.e. a tridiagonal matrix whose characteristic polynomial is your given polynomial) using a modification of the Euclidean algorithm. On the other hand, even if you do not want the eigenvalues of this special tridiagonal matrix, the entries afford some diagnostic capabilities for checking if your polynomial has all its roots real. Here's how to build the diagonal and one of the off-diagonals:

```
p = LegendreP[6, x]; n = Exponent[p, x];
p0 = p/Coefficient[p, x, n];
p1 = D[p0/n, x];
{d, e} = MapAt[Most, Transpose[Reap[
     Do[
      {q, r} = PolynomialQuotientRemainder[p0, p1, x];
      s = If[TrueQ[r == 0], 0, Coefficient[-r, x, Exponent[r, x]]];
      If[k < n, p0 = p1;
       p1 = If[TrueQ[r == 0], (#/Coefficient[#, x, Exponent[#, x]]) &[D[p1, x]], -r/s]];
      Sow[{-Coefficient[q, x, 0], s}];
      , {k, n}]][[2, 1]]], 2]
{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {5/11, 8/33, 5/21, 8/35, 1/5}}
```

The result needed is this: if all the entries of the off-diagonal `e` are nonnegative, then all the roots of the polynomial are real. (See the papers linked to for more details.) Clearly, this is the case:

```
And @@ NonNegative[e]
True
```

If you want to see the actual roots themselves,

```
Eigenvalues[N[SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> d,
     Band[{2, 1}] -> Sqrt[e], Band[{1, 2}] -> Sqrt[e]}], 20]] // Sort
{-0.93246951420315202781, -0.66120938646626451366,
-0.23861918608319690863, 0.23861918608319690863,
0.66120938646626451366, 0.93246951420315202781}
```

or alternatively, `Eigenvalues[N[SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> d, Band[{2, 1}] -> e, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1}], 20]] // Sort`.

Compare:

```
x /. NSolve[LegendreP[6, x], x, 20]
{-0.93246951420315202781, -0.66120938646626451366,
-0.23861918608319690863, 0.23861918608319690863,
0.66120938646626451366, 0.93246951420315202781}
```

Comment: As a caveat: the method will break on some polynomials with complex roots, but it is guaranteed to furnish the diagonal and off-diagonal if the roots of the given polynomial are all real.