# Factoring polynomials to factors involving complex coefficients

Tags: simplifying-expressions, polynomials, complex, algebraic-manipulation, factorization

I've run into some problems using `Factor` on polynomials with complex coefficient factors. Reading the documentation it looks like it only factors over the `Integers` by default. So I've found I can factor some polynomials with complex factors using this:

```
Factor[ poly, Extension -> I ]
```

For example, the polynomial $$x^2+1$$ won't factor with just `Factor[x^2+1]`, however it does factor properly when I add the imaginary unit extension.

The unexpected problem I experienced is that another polynomial such as $$8x^3-7x^2+10x-5$$ still won't be factorized - even with the imaginary extension added!

What am I missing here? How do I simply get `Mathematica` to completely factor any polynomial with complex factors I give it?

Comment: The specific output I am after is a product of first degree polynomials. For example $x^2+1$ factors into (x-i)(x+i).
 Another Example:
$4x^3-8x^2-x+2$ factors as $(x-2)(2x-1)(2x+1)$

Comment: @Artes Ok, I added it back.

Comment: [The associated math.SE question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170071)

Comment: @jcelios To addres the question this answer includes the issues (implicitly present here) which could be also interesting for you : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6740/checking-if-the-roots-of-a-function-are-real/6742#6742

Comment: @J.M. This link is interesting purely on the mathematical layer, however to discuss in the greater extent the algorithmic layer we need more specific information.

Comment: @Artes: I know that; I was pointing out that the user had asked an associated question on math.SE that seems to come from the same motivation as this question's.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

By default `Mathematica` can factorize polynomials to lower order ones in terms of integers if it's possible. `Extension` serves factorization over the rationals extended by a finite set of algebraic numbers, i.e. any element of the extension is a finite combination of rationals and algebraics $(a_1, a_2,...,a_n)$. The fundamental theorem of algebra states that in principle one can always factorize any polynomial of one variable by finding its roots, nevertheless there are fundamental limitations (Galois theorem, Abel's impossibility theorem,  etc.) as well as technical problems (simplifying roots in terms of nested radicals, efficency, etc.).

This polynomial :

```
p[x_] := 8 x^3 - 7 x^2 + 10 x - 5
```

has three complex roots (only one real) :

```
 s = Solve[ p[x] == 0, x]
```

[image]

involving irrational numbers and therefore it cannot be factorized by default nor using `Extension->I`. The roots are algebraic numbers since `p[x]` is a polynomial with integer coefficients :

```
Element[#, Algebraics] & /@ s[[All, 1, 2]]
```

> ```
> {True, True, True}
> ```

so it implies we can factorize `p[x]` using an appropriate `Extension`. 
In order to factor `p[x]` completely one should use the field of the rationals numbers extended by  the roots of the polynomial e.g.

```
Factor[ p[x],  Extension -> {Root[p[x], 1], Root[p[x], 2], Root[p[x], 3]}]
```

However since this expression produces the output in terms of `Root` objects, one would prefer it in terms of radicals, e.g.

```
Factor[ p[x], Extension -> ToRadicals @ {Root[p[x], 1], Root[p[x], 2], Root[p[x], 3]}] // 
        Together // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

We could also proceed along a different route, taking only terms that cause the roots are not rational numbers. Therefore we select these numbers : 
 `{(2143 + 72 Sqrt[2230])^(1/3), Sqrt[3], I}`.  We included `I` because two of the roots are complex.

```
Factor[ p[x], Extension -> {(2143 + 72 Sqrt[2230])^(1/3), Sqrt[3], I}] // Together
        // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

There is yet another (a bit more involved) way to factorize this polynomial using `FactorList`, which results in this case in the simplest form :

```
Times @@ Simplify /@ Power @@@ 
  FactorList[ p[x],
              Extension -> ToRadicals @ { Root[p[x], 1], Root[p[x], 2], Root[p[x], 3]}]//
  TraditionalForm
```

[image]

`FactorList` made possible simplifying every factor instead of using `Simplify` to the result of `Factor` which produced expanded form of the polylomial. Although the last factorization is not much simpler than appropriate multiplying terms like `(x - ToRadicals @ Root[ p[x], i] @ )`, there is an aspect which makes functions like `Factor` really useful, e.g. when one encounters the problem of expressing roots in terms of radicals, consider a very simple example :

```
FullSimplify @ Solve[ MinimalPolynomial[Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[5]][x] == 0, x]
```

[image]

To overcome this problem one could use e.g. an appropriate `ComplexityFunction` to simplify completely the radicals, but in general this is far from being obvious how one should proceed. Nevertheless if we know what the `Extension` should be, then the answer is simple, e.g.

```
Factor[ 4 - 16 #1^2 + #1^4 &[x], Extension -> {Sqrt[3], Sqrt[5]}]
```

[image]

or

```
Factor[ -  27 Sqrt[3] + 189 x - 189 Sqrt[3] x^2 + 315 x^3 
        - 105 Sqrt[3] x^4 + 63 x^5 - 7 Sqrt[3] x^6 + x^7,   Extension -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the output form I'm looking for (See the comment on the original post). I've always been under the impression that fully factoring a polynomial meant putting it into the form of a product of first degree and/or constant polynomials.

$$(Ax+a)(Bx+b)(Cx+c)...$$

Since the results you've posted contain at least one second degree polynomial (I see an x^2 for example) I'm not sure why it's considered a properly factored output. But perhaps there is a semantic or notational confusion issue.

Comment: As well is it simply not possible to tell mathematica to factor over the set of complex numbers rather then just the rationals + some specific given algebraic numbers? Or does this lead into issues with Non-Computable Transcendental Numbers? If so I should think it would be possible to simply factor over all Computable Algebraic Numbers (given enough computing power of course).

Comment: You had an integer coefficient polynomial, so its roots are algebraic numbers.  The edit of my post should clarify your doubts. I factorized `p[x]` to three first order polynomials taking an appropriate extension field.

Comment: @jcelios Facorizatoion over all algebraic numbers is not possible. You can only take a finite number of algebraics to proceed with factorization of polynomials.

Comment: This may be too far beyond the scope of my original question (or this site for that matter) but why isn't it possible? It's not that I don't believe you, I'm just curious.

Comment: Before answering your question, reply if my edit of the post clarified a bit your doubts.

Comment: Yes it did, thank you.

Comment: @jcelios I'm glad I could help. I'll update my answer to include possible problems with this issue, but it will take about one hour.

Comment: If one wanted a full factorization, something like `Times @@ (x - Table[Simplify[ToRadicals[Root[Function[x, #], k]]], {k, Exponent[#, x]}] &[8 x^3 - 7 x^2 + 10 x - 5])` could be done, but `ToRadicals[]` won't always succeed in converting `Root[]` objects to explicit radicals. For polynomials of degree greater than five, it is unlikely to get explicit radical expressions for the roots for an arbitrary polynomial (per Abel).

Comment: @J.M. The link I added in the previous comment slightly touches this problem.

Answer (score 12):

More concise, but same idea as in Artes' approach (which I upvoted, but I'm adding this anyway because it won't squeeze into a comment).

```
factorCompletely[poly_, x_] := Module[
  {solns, lcoeff},
  solns = Solve[poly == 0, x, Cubics -> False, Quartics -> False];
  lcoeff = Coefficient[poly, x^Exponent[poly, x]];
  lcoeff*(Times @@ (x - (x /. solns)))
  ]
```

Examples:

```
p[x_] := 8 x^3 - 7 x^2 + 10 x - 5

factorCompletely[p[x], x]

(* Out[66]= 8 (x - Root[-5 + 10 #1 - 7 #1^2 + 8 #1^3 & , 1]) 
   (x - Root[-5 + 10 #1 - 7 #1^2 + 8 #1^3 & , 2]) 
   (x - Root[-5 + 10 #1 - 7 #1^2 + 8 #1^3 & , 3]) *)

factorCompletely[ 4 x^3 - 8 x^2 - x + 2, x]

(* Out[67]= 4 (-2 + x) (-(1/2) + x) (1/2 + x) *)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 fullFactor[f_, x_] := Roots[f == 0, x] /. Equal -> ((#1 - #2) &) /. Or -> Times
 fullFactor[x^5 - 1, x]
 (* (-1 + x) ((-1)^(1/5) + x) (-(-1)^(2/5) + x) ((-1)^(3/5) + x) (-(-1)^(4/5) + x) *)
```

Answer (score 3):

For a polynomial of arbitrary degree > 4, of course in general Mathematica, and nobody, may be able to factor it in any reasonable way because its roots may not be expressible in terms of radicals. But for degree <= 4, and in various higher-degree special cases, you could exploit `Solve`. E.g.,

```
p[x_]:=8 x^3-7 x^2+10 x-5
Times @@ (x - y /. (Solve[p[x] == 0, x] /. x -> y))
```

Comment: `Factor` is advantageous, to see it  try e.g. `Times @@ (x - y /. (Solve[4 - 16 #1^2 + #1^4 &[x] == 0, x] /. x -> y))` and `Factor[4 - 16 #1^2 + #1^4 &[x], Extension -> {Sqrt[3], Sqrt[5]}]`.

Comment: No doubt using `Factor` with specified extensions can provide a simpler result. But doing so requires already knowing which quadratic, or other, extensions to use!