# Plotting solutions of a 4th order polynomial equation

Tags: plotting, polynomials

I have a polynomial equation of the fourth order, which has $4$ roots depending on a variable parameter `s1`. For each `s1` I have $4$ solutions. I need a `LinePlot` of all roots to see how they move in the complex plane when the parameter `s1` changes. I can solve my equation but I don't know how to plot all the roots together on one diagram  (points connected with line for each solution).

```
poly = -6.110000000000001`*^6 k^4 + 1000.` s1^2 + 60.335263000000005`(-5.` k + s1)^2;

Table[ NSolve[ poly == 0, k], {s1, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}}]
```

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15637/5478

Comment: You have already asked quite similar question and I think you've seen e.g. this [Factoring a two variable polynomial in a special way](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38602/factoring-a-two-variable-polynomial-in-a-special-way/38607#38607), in fact, this answers your question.

Comment: I don't understand light and dark green and lines there while roots moving

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `RootLocusPlot`.

```
poly = -6.110000000000001`*^6 k^4 + 1000.` s1^2 + 60.335263000000005` (-5.` k + s1)^2;

RootLocusPlot[1/poly, {s1, 0, 1}, FeedbackType -> None, 
PoleZeroMarkers -> {"ParameterValues" -> Range[0.1, 0.9, 0.1]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Glad it solved your problem.