# Roots of a polynomial

Tags: plotting, manipulate, polynomials

In Mathematica I have represented the following polynomial $a x^4 + b x^2 + c x+2$ using the `Plot` command and, through the `Manipulate` command, it is possible to vary the parameters $a$, $b$, $c$. Now, however, I would like the program to give me back the roots of the polynomial according to the parameters $a$, $b$, $c$ .... could you help me kindly?

This is the code:

```
Manipulate[
  Plot[a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c*x + 2, {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20},{-20, 20}}]
  ,{a,-1, 1}
  ,{b,-10, 10}
  ,{c,-10, 10}
  ,ControlPlacement -> Right
]
```

Comment: Maybe some variant of `roots[a_, b_, c_] := x /. Solve[a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c*x + 2 == 0, x]`

Comment: Take a look at this post [Factoring a two variable polynomial in a special way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/38602/factoring-a-two-variable-polynomial-in-a-special-way/38607#38607). If you examine it, you should be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

As Dan Lichtblau has already commented you can use

```
Solve[a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c*x + 2 == 0, x]
```

to obtain the roots. But I suspect that you really, really, really don't want to do this. Why?

A long time ago, (in [The Mathematica Journal 9(3)](https://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i3/contents/Inout9-3/Inout9-3_6.html)), Daniel explained why you should use `Root` instead, e.g. via `Solve[a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c*x + 2 == 0, x, Quartics -> False]`

- The `Root` form is a *concise* way of expressing algebraic numbers via the minimal polynomial they satisfy, along with a canonical ordering in the complex plane (specified by the second argument of `Root`).
- To get a radical form, you can use `ToRadicals`. Clearly, this output is more complicated than the `Root` form.

In addition to size, there are other reasons to prefer the `Root` form:

- It is faster to obtain.
- It is numerically more stable to evaluate. In general, radical formulations are prone to numeric problems. `Root` objects do not have this liability.
- When the roots of an irreducible cubic are all real but not rational, the so-called [casus irreducibilus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CasusIrreducibilus.html) shows that they still must be expressed in terms of `I`. This means that numeric evaluation will give small imaginary parts unless, by happenstance, they exactly cancel. Small numeric error from round-off makes this unlikely.
- For sufficiently complicated algebraics, it is often faster to evaluate the `Root` form numerically, at least at high precision.
- Polynomial combinations of `Root` objects simplify using `RootSum` and `RootReduce`.
- Derivatives of `Root` objects with respect to a *parameter* are expressed in terms of `Root` objects. This is useful for (eigenvalue) sensitivity analysis.

So, for all practical computation, you are better off working with `Root` objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   StringForm["roots = ``",
    roots = x /. NSolve[a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c*x + 2 == 0, x]],
   Spacer[5],
   Plot[a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c*x + 2, {x, -20, 20},
    PlotRange -> 20,
    Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], 
      Tooltip[Point[{#, 0}], #] & /@ Cases[roots, _Real]}]}],
 {a, -1, 1, 0.02, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {b, -10, 10, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {c, -10, 10, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** If you also wish to see the roots in the complex plane

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   StringForm["roots = ``",
    roots = x /. NSolve[a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c*x + 2 == 0, x]],
   Spacer[5],
   Plot[a*x^4 + b*x^2 + c*x + 2, {x, -20, 20},
    PlotRange -> 20,
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"x", "f[x]"}),
    Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], 
      Tooltip[Point[{#, 0}], #] & /@ Cases[roots, _Real]}],
   Spacer[5],
   ListPlot[Tooltip /@ ReIm /@ roots,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[4]],
    PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}},
    AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {Re, Im})]}],
 {a, -1, 1, 0.02, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {b, -10, 10, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 {c, -10, 10, 0.2, Appearance -> "Labeled", ImageSize -> Small},
 ControlPlacement -> Right]
```

[image]