# Apart for complex roots?

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

Let `p[x]` be a polynomial in `x` and consider the partial fraction decomposition of `1/p[x].`

The function `Apart[]` fails in simple cases like this

```
Apart[1/(1 + x^2)]

(* Out[37]= 1/(1 + x^2) *)
```

We could define a function

```
cApart[invp_] := Module[{z, c},
   z = x /. Solve[0 == 1/invp, x];
   c[k_] := 
    Product[If[i != k, 1/(z[[k]] - z[[i]]), 1], {i, 1, Length[z]}];
   Sum[c[i]/(x - z[[i]]), {i, 1, Length[z]}]];
```

which does the job

```
cApart[1/(1 + x^2)]

(* Out[36] = -(I/(2 (-I + x))) + I/(2 (I + x)) *)
```

But my question: is there an option for Apart[] or another standard facility in Mathematica which gives the decomposition in general, i.e. in the complex domain?

**EDIT #1.1 Standard solution using Extension**

The hints given so far can be codensed in this example

```
With[{d = 1 + x + x^2}, 
 Apart[1/Factor[d, Extension -> (x /. Solve[d == 0, x])]]]

(* -(1/((-1 + 2 (-1)^(1/3)) (-1 + (-1)^(1/3) - x))) - 1/((-1 + 
    2 (-1)^(1/3)) ((-1)^(1/3) + x)) *)
```

But it turns out that this procedure is not useful in practical applications as it takes extremely long calculation times (e.g. 1+x+x^4 took to Long to wait for it).

The following form (or something similar) would be nice to have

```
Apart[1/p[x], Extension -> Complexes] (* proposal, not available *)
```

**EDIT #1.2 Other applications of cApart**

It is interesting to apply cApart to a polynomial of higher degree

```
cApart[1/(1 + x + x^6)]

(* 
Out[64]= 
 1/((x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1] -
       Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6])) + 
 1/((x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6])) + 
 1/((x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6])) + 
 1/((x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6])) + 
 1/((x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5]) (Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5] - 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6])) + 
 1/((x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6]) (-Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5] + 
      Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6]))
*)
```

Which gives the solution in a very regular pattern involving the function Root[].
The numeric evaluation gives

```
% // N

(*
Out[65]= -((
  0.0965468 + 0.0295033 I)/((-0.945402 - 0.611837 I) + x)) - (
 0.0965468 - 0.0295033 I)/((-0.945402 + 0.611837 I) + x) - (
 0.084438 + 0.114801 I)/((0.154735 - 1.03838 I) + x) - (
 0.084438 - 0.114801 I)/((0.154735 + 1.03838 I) + x) + (
 0.180985 - 0.279696 I)/((0.790667 - 0.300507 I) + x) + (
 0.180985 + 0.279696 I)/((0.790667 + 0.300507 I) + x)
*)
```

We can even continue to use these symbolic Root[] expressions in more complicated environments such as

```
g[a_] = Integrate[
  Exp[-a x]/(x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1]), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
  Assumptions -> a > 0]

(* Out[69]= E^(-a Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1]) (-I \[Pi] - 
   CoshIntegral[a Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1]] - 
   SinhIntegral[a Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1]]) *)
```

It is gratifying that the integral is evaluated symbolically.
We can now easily calculate numerical values, e.g.

g[1.]

(* Out[70]= 0.653737 - 0.158332 I *)

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Maybe [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2001/Aug/msg00144.html) is related?

Comment: You can do this: `Apart@Factor[1/(x^2 + 1), Extension -> I]`. This answer is closely related [Factoring polynomials to factors involving complex coefficients](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8255/factoring-polynomials-to-factors-involving-complex-coefficients/8257#8257). `Apart`

Comment: @Artes: Thanks. It looks good but it fails for 1/(1+x^3) which is not completely decomposed or 1/(1+x+x^2) which is not decomposed at all (Version 8).

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze  `Extension` depends on a case by case basis of course. Here this works:  `Apart@Factor[1/(1 + x^3), Extension -> {(-1)^(1/3)}]` or even better `FullSimplify /@ 
 Apart@Factor[1/(1 + x^3), Extension -> {(-1)^(1/3), I}]`

Comment: @ mikuszefski: thanks for this link where they give an interesting generalization to Extension of the hint of Artes: for example With[{d = 1 + x + x^6}, 
 Apart[1/Factor[d, Extension -> (x /. Solve[d == 0, x])]]] but takes much more time than my Routine.

Comment: @Artes: thank you. So you need to know in advance which Extension to take. In the link of mikuszefski I found the general form of Extension. But as stated in my comment to him, this is elegant but takes rather long time to be evaluated.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze Most of the time the elegant solution is the fast one, but I agree that this is not always the case. Your code looks quite short and efficient (although I would generalize it a bit, e.g. introducing  function parameter `var_` in case it is not `x` and using `Denominator[]` to treat, well, only the denominator...).

Comment: I highly appreciate your solution, but it has two shortcomings. Firstly the numerator is fixed to 1, and secondly it does not work for multiple roots. It is really pity that Wolfram does not implement this most general form of Apart.

Comment: There are both [ExtendedApart](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ExtendedApart/) and [ApartAll](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ApartAll/) in the Wolfram Function Repository.

Answer (score 14):

Re: "But my question: is there an option for Apart[] or another standard facility in Mathematica which gives the decomposition in general, i.e. in the complex domain?"

There's `` Integrate`ComplexApart[p[x], x] ``:

```
Integrate`ComplexApart[1/(x^2 + 1), x]
```

> $$\frac{i}{2 (x+i)}-\frac{i}{2 (x-i)}$$

```
Integrate`ComplexApart[1/(1 + x + x^6), x]
```

> $\frac{-7776 \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,6\right]+6480
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,6\right]^2-5400
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,6\right]^3+4500
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,6\right]^4-3750
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,6\right]^5-3125}{43531
>    \left(x-\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,6\right]\right)}+\frac{-7776
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,5\right]+6480
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,5\right]^2-5400
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,5\right]^3+4500
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,5\right]^4-3750
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,5\right]^5-3125}{43531
>    \left(x-\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,5\right]\right)}+\frac{-7776
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,4\right]+6480
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,4\right]^2-5400
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,4\right]^3+4500
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,4\right]^4-3750
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,4\right]^5-3125}{43531
>    \left(x-\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,4\right]\right)}+\frac{-7776
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,3\right]+6480
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,3\right]^2-5400
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,3\right]^3+4500
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,3\right]^4-3750
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,3\right]^5-3125}{43531
>    \left(x-\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,3\right]\right)}+\frac{-7776
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,2\right]+6480
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,2\right]^2-5400
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,2\right]^3+4500
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,2\right]^4-3750
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,2\right]^5-3125}{43531
>    \left(x-\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,2\right]\right)}+\frac{-7776
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,1\right]+6480
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,1\right]^2-5400
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,1\right]^3+4500
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,1\right]^4-3750
>    \text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,1\right]^5-3125}{43531
>    \left(x-\text{Root}\left[\text{$\#$1}^6+\text{$\#$1}+1\&,1\right]\right)}$

---

I (re?)discovered `Factor[..., Extension -> All]` today in V13, which may or may not have worked since year 1. It gives the complete factorization of a polynomial, which is needed for the partial fractions decomposition. However, `Apart` does not always seem to succeed.

```
(* SUCCESS *)
Apart[Factor[1/(1 + x^6), Extension -> All]] // Map@Simplify
(*
I/(6 I - 6 x) + I/(6 I + 6 x) +
 1/(6 - 3 (-I + Sqrt[3]) x) + 1/(6 + 3 (-I + Sqrt[3]) x) +
 1/(6 - 3 (I + Sqrt[3]) x) + 1/(6 + 3 (I + Sqrt[3]) x)
*)

(* FAILURE *)
Apart[Factor[1/(1 + x + x^6), Extension -> All]]
(*
-(1/((x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 1]) *
     (x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 2]) *
     (x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 3]) *
     (x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 4]) *
     (x - Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 5]) *
     (-x + Root[1 + #1 + #1^6 &, 6])))
*)
```

Applying the `x /. Solve[..]` method in **Edit #1** of the OP ran for minutes before I killed it:

```
With[{d = (1 + x + x^6)},
 Apart[1/Factor[d, Extension -> (x /. Solve[d == 0, x])]]]
```

---

*Update 2023.03.24*

There are (since 2020) resource functions that accomplish partial fractions decompositions over extensions of the rationals:

- [`ResourceFunction["ExtendedApart"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ApartAll/)
- [`ResourceFunction["ApartAll"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/ExtendedApart/)

Comment: It does not appear to be `Root[]` per se for it fails when we replace them by a compound numeric expression: `Apart[Factor[1/(1 + x + x^6), Extension -> All] /. Verbatim[Root][_, n_, ___] :> Sin[n]]`.  But `Apart` works if the `Root[]` objects are replaced by symbols.