# Partial fraction expansion with complex numbers

Tags: functions

$$\text{Apart}\left[\frac{1}{x^4+1}\right]$$

Does nothing. How can I get it to expand it. Sometimes it is useful.

Comment: See this question: [68824](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68824/apart-for-complex-roots).

Comment: @Mahdi $$\text{Apart}\left[\text{Factor}\left[\frac{1}{x^4+1},\text{Extension}\to i\right]\right]$$ gives only $$\frac{i}{2 \left(x^2+i\right)}-\frac{i}{2 \left(x^2-i\right)}$$ and $$\text{Apart}\left[\text{Factor}\left[\frac{1}{x^4+2},\text{Extension}\to i\right]\right]$$ straight up does not work

Comment: What is expected result for the first one? For the second one: `Apart@Factor[1/(1 + x^2), Extension -> {(-1)^(1/2), I}]`?

Comment: Your question is a partial case of the [Mittag-Leffler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem) for the expansion of meromorphic functions. There is a nice demo [here](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MittagLefflerExpansionsOfMeromorphicFunctions/).

Comment: @yarchik oh I love that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apart for complex roots?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68824/apart-for-complex-roots)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found by trial and error that Extension-> Sqrt[I] does the job.

```
ExpToTrig[Apart[Factor[1/(1 + x^4), Extension -> Sqrt[I]]]]
```

$$\frac{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{4}}{\sqrt{2} \left(-x+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}+\frac{\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i}{4}}{\sqrt{2} \left(x+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\frac{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{4}}{\sqrt{2} \left(-x-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}-\frac{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{4}}{\sqrt{2} \left(x-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}$$

Here ExpToTrig is not really required but it does the final beautifying.

Comment: would there be any way to do something like:
        ExpToTrig[
 Apart[Factor[1/(1 + x^4), Extension -> Roots[1 + x^4 == 0, x]]]]

Comment: @grdgfgr How about `ExpToTrig[Apart[Factor[1/(1 + x^4), Extension -> (x /. Solve[1 + x^4 == 0, x])]]]`?

Comment: @ kirma : that seems to be the general rule setting the Extension to the roots of the polynomial in question. From Help: Extension
is an option for various polynomial and algebraic functions that specifies generators for the algebraic number field to be used.

Comment: @GappyHilmore `Apart[Factor[1/(1 + x^4), Extension -> All]]` works and so does `Apart[Factor[1/(2 + x^4), Extension -> All]]` (in V13 but maybe it didn't back then).

Answer (score 3):

There's an internal function:

```
Integrate`ComplexApart[1/(1 + x^4), x]
(*
-((-1)^(1/4)/(4 (-(-1)^(1/4) + x))) +
 (-1)^(1/4)/(4 ((-1)^(1/4) + x)) -
 (-1)^(3/4)/(4 (-(-1)^(3/4) + x)) +
 (-1)^(3/4)/(4 ((-1)^(3/4) + x))
*)
```

Comment: fyi, in Maple they have 2 functions.   `parfrac` and `fullparfrac` for using complex domain. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GJ9w.png)  It looks like `fullparfrac` is like `ComplexApart` you show.

Comment: @Nasser With so many top-level (System) functions in Mathematica, you would think `ComplexApart` would be among them.