# Approximating Exp[-x] in partial fraction form

Tags: numerics, series-expansion, approximation

I'm looking to obtain order-$k$ approximation of $\exp(-z)$ for real-valued $z$.
$$R_k(z)\approx \exp(-z)$$

The constraint is that I need the result in partial fraction form, ie:

$$
\begin{equation}
R_k(z)=\alpha_0 + \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\alpha_i}{z-\lambda_i}
\label{1}
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
$$

Where $\{\alpha_i\}$ and $\{\lambda_i\}$ are either complex-valued or real-valued. Restricting to real-valued allows doubling $k$ without increasing computational cost.

There's this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103397/chebyshev-approximation) for Chebychev approximation and `PadeApproximant`, but **how do I turn those rational functions into partial fraction form $\ref{1}$?**

All of the examples I tried have imaginary roots, so `Apart` fails to factor some terms.

Appendix B of this [paper](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Esaad/PDF/CSRD_90_969.pdf) gives one such set of coefficients, but that's not easy to experiment with in Mathematica.

Here's a naive attempt at order=4 approximation with Taylor series.

[image]

```
Clear[x, t, i];
k = 4;

poly = Normal@Series[Exp[t], {t, 0, k}];
dpoly = Function @@ {{t}, D[poly, t]};

roots = t /. {ToRules@Roots[poly == 0, t]};
alpha[0] = 0;
alpha[i_] := dpoly[roots[[i]]]^-1;
lambda[i_] := roots[[i]];
nexp[z_] := alpha[0] + Sum[alpha[i]/(z - lambda[i]), {i, 1, k}];

LogPlot @@ {{Exp[-z], nexp[z]}, {z, 1, 10}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"exp[-z]", "approx"}, AxesLabel -> {"z"}, 
  PlotLabel -> StringForm["Order `` approximation", k]}
Table[{alpha[i], lambda[i]} // N, {i, 0, k}] // 
 TableForm[#, TableHeadings -> {None, {"alpha", "lambda"}}] &
```

Comment: The linked paper considers only real lambdas, but I see complex lambdas in the table from your question. Is it OK?

Comment: Here's [Table 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhZRC.png) in that paper, it uses complex numbers. Real-valued would work too, didn't know that was possible

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Comment: If $z=10$ how do you get the "value" being -10?  $e^{-10}\approx 0.0000453999$.

Comment: value in the graph is the logarithm of the function in question

Comment: Understood.  So you're trying to estimate $\log(e^{-z})=-z$ with a complicated function?  Obviously I must be missing the point.

Comment: Removed the graph since it seems to be confusing

Comment: If you need the coefficients of a particular model ($R_k(z)$), just generate a bunch of points for $z$ values of interest and perform a regression.

Comment: @JimB The issue is that I don't have a way to compute $\exp(-z)$, but I do have a method to compute 1/(z-x). So the above approximation gives a way to express exponential in terms of inverses. Section 3 of this [paper](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~saad/PDF/CSRD_90_969.pdf) gives background

Comment: If you have a Pade approximation you can use Apart to get a PFD.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I need linear factors, but `Apart` gives me quadratic factors because of complex roots

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/68824/apart-for-complex-roots and linked questions.  There's also a resource function for this.