# Code I get from wolfram isn't working in mathematica

Tags: polynomials, factorization

I need to perform the factor as shown here

```
factor(s^5+32s^4+363s^3+2092s^2+5052s+4320)
```

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor(s%5E5%2B32s%5E4%2B363s%5E3%2B2092s%5E2%2B5052s%2B4320)

I copy the code for the irreduciable factorization

```
N[Factor[s^5 + 32 s^4 + 363 s^3 + 2092 s^2 + 5052 s + 4320, Extension -> Flatten[s /. Solve[s^5 + 32 s^4 + 363 s^3 + 2092 s^2 + 5052 s + 4320 == 0, s]]]]
```

I try to run it on mathematica and its been like 5 minutes and it still isn't not done. I a running Mathematica 11 Student Edition (11.2)

Comment: Related: [Factoring polynomials to factors involving complex coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8255/45431).

Comment: I'm really new to mathematica, I really don't understand why if i copy the code from wolfram to use in mathematica it doesnt work. I don't understand 99% of what is being said in that thread. I'm only using mathematica to verify calculations that I had to do in matlab and labview for a controls class, and its working wonderfully for everything but that factor.

Comment: I have reported this issue to Wolfram. As soon as I have the confirmation that this is a bug (or a solution) I will give an update.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe your question is completely valid and I gave it a big upvote. Assuming that WolframAlpha did indeed use this command to get the result, I'm not sure on what mystical machine they ran it on.

I let it evaluate for several hours on the latest Mathematica version without success and my machine is pretty strong performance wise. I also tested older versions with the same result.

The only thing I can state is that it is indeed supposed to work. You can try a slightly simpler version of this problem by taking out the highest powers

```
Factor[4320 + 5052 s + 2092 s^2, 
  Extension -> Flatten[s /. Solve[4320 + 5052 s + 2092 s^2 == 0, s]]]
(* 
  1/523 (-1263 I + 3 Sqrt[73799] - 1046 I s) (1263 I + 3 Sqrt[73799] + 1046 I s)
*)
```

If you are really interested in this, then I would write to Wolfram support.

### Edit:

I did not notice that [Chip](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4346/chip-hurst) works with the W|A team. Please see his answer which reflects what Wolfram support sent me:

> Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support.
>
> As user Chip Hurst (a Wolfram|Alpha developer here) mentioned in his comment, this is an issue with Wolfram|Alpha returning the wrong expression it actually used to obtain the result. We hope to address this W|A issue soon.
>
> We appreciate you taking the time to bring this to our attention. Please do not hesitate to contact us with anything else you come across while using our products.

Comment: that worked perfectly, thank you

Comment: @halirutan i wonder what is up with their quality assurance and testing department

Answer (score 29):

You can chalk this up as a W|A bug.

We do indeed try to factor with the approach stated by OP. When that times out, we try a different approach, but fail to update the code provided to the user.

The approach used in the timeout case is essentially

```
poly = s^5 + 32s^4 + 363s^3 + 2092s^2 + 5052s + 4320;
sols = s /. Solve[poly == 0, s];

N[Times @@ (s - sols)]
```

> ```
> ((2.04832 - 0.52209 I) + s) ((2.04832 + 0.52209 I) + s) ((5.55913 - 5.16689 I) + s) ((5.55913 + 5.16689 I) + s) (16.7851 + s)
> ```

(Remove `N` to see the exact solution.)

### Edit

This has been fixed now and will appear once W|A hits its next release cycle. The code will be

```
With[{poly = s^5 + 32 s^4 + 363 s^3 + 2092 s^2 + 5052 s + 4320},
  Coefficient[poly, s, Exponent[poly, s]] Apply[Times, s - (s /. Solve[poly == 0, s])]
]
```

### Edit 2

This has been fixed for a few weeks now:
[image]