# Factoring the Quadratic Polynomial $a x^2 +b x +c$

Tags: polynomials, factorization

I want mathematica to factor the quadratic polynomial $a x^2 +b x +c$ into this standard form $a(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$ with $r_1=-\frac{b}{2a}+\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ and $r_2=-\frac{b}{2a}-\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. I tried `Factor` and its `Extension` option but I could not get anyting.

Comment: Try `factorCompletely[a x^2 + b x + c, x]` from [Daniel's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10588/4999) to the question @Artes linked.

Comment: Closely related  [Factoring polynomials to factors involving complex coefficients](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8255/factoring-polynomials-to-factors-involving-complex-coefficients)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a Times @@ (y - # & /@ (x /. Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]))
```

Comment: (+1) Thanks. :)  But, why they really made `Factor`? :D  Also, you missed the coefficient $a$. :)

Comment: @H.R. This is similar to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8258/4999

Comment: @MichaelE2: Yes, you are right. I just saw that before you mentioned. :) Thanks by the way. :)