# Distribute transpose on matrix multiplication

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, algebraic-manipulation, algebra

I need to do the following:

```
Transpose[A.(B+C)]=Transpose[B].Transpose[A]+Transpose[C].Transpose[A]
```

How should I do this in mathematica? So far mathematica does not distribute the operation. Thank you!

Comment: The NCAlgebra package might be able to do this.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** it seems this only works in 10.1 and later, but not in 10.0.

This works:

```
Assuming[(a | b | c) ∈ Matrices[{d, d}], TensorExpand@Transpose[a.(b + c)]]

(* Transpose[b, {2, 1}].Transpose[a, {2, 1}] + Transpose[c, {2, 1}].Transpose[a, {2, 1}] *)
```

We needed to tell Mathematica that `a`, `b` and `c` are square matrices and use `TensorExpand`.

Check here: [Symbolic tensors](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SymbolicTensors.html).

Comment: What do the | change?

Comment: @space_voyager Check [Element](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html), third line from the top.

Comment: +1, just FTR it doesn't work in v9

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm sorry but doing what you said gives in Mathematica 10.0: `Transpose[b + c, {2, 1}].Transpose[a, {2, 1}]` which is not what I want. Suggestions?

Comment: @space_voyager You are right, I tried it in 10.2 only.

Comment: Yes there was a bug in 10.0 that prevented this from working. It is fixed in 10.1 and later versions.

Comment: @StefanR Is [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83429/12) a bug, or it's just how `Reduce` works?  I can't tell what's reasonable to expect from `Reduce`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Oh sorry you were asking a different question. Hmm... l'll look into it.

Comment: @Szabolcs How do I get rid of the `{2,1 }` that shows up in `Transpose[a, {2, 1}]`?

Comment: @space_voyager You can try `ReplaceAll`: `expr /. Transpose[a_, {2,1}] :> Transpose[a]` ... but for a matrix `Transpose[a]` is the same as `Transpose[2, {2,1}]`.